# Why I cant register two components of the same name using React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-tsx

I am using useForm hook produced by React Hook Form library. Because of the UI library that I use I am forced to create custom radio buttons. My problem is that even i have a type in interface that defines the form when I try to register two components of same name I am getting an warning that says:

```
'Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `NewForm`.
    at ToggleButton (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1236:23)'
```

Here is the interface and type:

```
interface FormInput {
  dynamicFieldTitle: string;
  formTitle: string;
  tokenType: TokenType;
  tokenAddress: string;
  tokenId: string;
  expirationDate: string;
}

type TokenType = "ERC1155" | "ERC721";
```

And here is the JSX code:

```
    <ToggleButton
      {...register("tokenType")}
      onClick={toggleButtonHandler}
      position="left"
      selected={!isERC1155}
    >
      ERC721
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
      {...register("tokenType")}
      onClick={toggleButtonHandler}
      position="right"
      selected={isERC1155}
    >
      ERC1155
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: What makes you think the error has anything to do with doing things twice? It's telling you that something is trying to use a ref on a function component, which you can't do on a plain function component; instead, it has to be wrapped using `forwardRef` (as the error says) and then it has to put the ref on something it renders. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 1):

`register` method allows you to register an input or select element. it returns some methods, one of which is `ref`. In **React** you can't pass `ref` to a function component. instead you have to wrap the function component in `forwardRef`. like this:

```
// not working, because ref is not assigned
<TextInput {...register('test')} />

const firstName = register('firstName', { required: true })
<TextInput
  onChange={firstName.onChange}
  onBlur={firstName.onBlur}
  inputRef={firstName.ref} // you can achieve the same for different ref name such as innerRef
/>

// correct way to forward input's ref
const Select = React.forwardRef(({ onChange, onBlur, name, label }, ref) => (
  <select name={name} ref={ref} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur}>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
));
```

- to work with custom component (e.g. UI library) **React-hook-form** recommends to use `useController` hook or `Controller` component.
- if you want to manually register your custom component you will need to update the input value with setValue.e.g.

```
register('firstName', { required: true, min: 8 });

<TextInput onTextChange={(value) => setValue('lastChange', value))} />
```

you can follow the **RHF** document. https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/

**useController** https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller